# Double logging with Nlog in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog

I'm using a simple new empty project with Nlog:.

This is `appsettings.json` file :

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Debug" 

    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

The `program.cs` file is :

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                }).ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Debug);
                })
                .UseNLog();
```

In my controller I do simple a logging operation:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("***test***");
        return Ok();
    }
```

(`nlog.config` file was removed here for verbosity).

When I run a simple test, I get this :

[image]

The red rectangle is the Nlog template ( with the message).

**But** look what happens at the arrows at the top. There is an additional logged message.

This is becuase of that line :

```
   logging.AddConsole();
```

If I remove that line, I get this :

[image]

Which is fine, **But** then I don't see the "startup logs" (url,port , application started message) which I do need.

**Question:**

How can I get rid of the red section only, when logging messages :

[image]

Comment: Why didn't you post the NLog config? I'd say you don't need AddConsole, because console can be configured as NLog target, and I'd guess that you have something in the NLog config that prevents Micorsoft logs from being written into the console, like  <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Warn"  final="true" /> may be.

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh You're absolutly right.  here it is : https://pastebin.com/4e1D3Ha8 .

Comment: Funny thing actually: I do remember I had these "now listening on" and so on messages, I guess with nlog, because we've been using it for a long time. Now that I checked it in our application and these startup messages are not there anymore.

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh  Theses messages are important to see when app was up and down..... but I only want them. not their "dbg" syymbols. for this - I added NLOG

Comment: To get this you could also inherit from BackgroundService and inject into this IHostApplicationLifetime. Than you can register for a number of events, like AppStarted, AppStopped, but also e.g. AppStopping. You can do all kind of things there, including writing your own start-stop messages with NLog. If needed, I could provide a sample. You can of course do the same just in the Configure method, without the BackgroundService overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your NLog.config to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="info"
      internalLogFile="logs/internal-nlog.txt">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions> 

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="lifetimeConsole"
            layout="${level:truncate=4:tolower=true}\: ${logger}[0]${newline}      ${message}${exception:format=tostring}" />

    <target xsi:type="Console" name="Console"
            layout="${longdate} ${newline} ▌ ${when:when=length('${aspnet-item:variable:requestId}')>0:Inner=${aspnet-item:variable:requestId}:else=${mdlc:item=requestId} } ${newline} ▌ ${when:when=length('${aspnet-item:variable:phoneCarKey}')>0:Inner=${aspnet-item:variable:phoneCarKey}:else=${mdlc:item=phoneCarKey} } ${newline} ▌ url: ${aspnet-request-url} ${newline} ▌ message: ${message}  ${newline} ▌ callsite : ${callsite} ${newline} ▌ ${when:when=length('${exception}')>0:Inner=exception \: }${exception:format=message,type,method,stacktrace}" />
  </targets>
 
  <rules>
    <!--Output hosting lifetime messages to make Docker / Visual Studio happy -->
    <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" level="Info" writeTo="lifetimeConsole" final="true" /> 
    <!--Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="Console" /> 
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Have added an extra LoggingRule for the Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime, so you can get the wanted startup logging.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Hosting-Lifetime-Startup-Messages

Comment: Thanks man. Tomorrow at the office I will check it 

Comment: What about the c# configuration , which should i keep?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Probably follow the wiki there: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3#4-update-programcs

Comment: @RoyiNamir Btw. one should not use `throwExceptions="true"` in production. It should only be used for last-resort troubleshooting. Instead it is recommended to use `throwConfigExceptions="true"`.

Comment: @RoyiNamir If using NLog.Web.AspNetCore ver. 4.12.0 then `lifetimeConsole` can just use `layout="${MicrosoftConsoleLayout}"`.

Comment: Removing AddConsole() and putting this ^ nlog config. solved it. Thank you.